# What is CDN ? & how to setup CDN in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cdn

How to setup CDN in Magento 2? 
How it benefits/improve site performance?

Answer (score 0):

> CDN is short for content delivery network. A content delivery network
>   is a system of distributed servers (network) that deliver pages and
>   other web content to a user, based on the geographic locations of the
>   user, the origin of the webpage and the content delivery server.

to configure CDN you need to add media and static base url, points to CDN service.
in CDN service you need to configure your web site origin url and path.

[image]

CDN will not make your web site faster, it simply unloads your assets.
it will probably help you if your level of shop is "`Aliexpress.com`"

Comment: What is the understanding about the base url of static files ?